# start qtimer from another class faces segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qtimer

I'm facing a problem using QTimer. The program closes with a segmentation fault in run time and when I exclude the "timer" from code, it runs properly. Here's the code:

```
Class A : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    A(QPixmap pic){
        this->setPixmap(pic);
    }
    void start(){
        timer = new QTimer();
        timer->start(1000);
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(moveObject()));
    }
public slots:
    void moveObject(){
        moveTimer = new QTimer();
        moveTimer->start(20);
        connect(moveTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(changePosition()));
    }
    void changePosition(){
        //a couple of things are done here
    }
private:
    QTimer *timer;
    QTimer *moveTimer;
}

Class B : QGraphicsView{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    B(QWidget *parent = 0) : QGraphicsView(parent){
        a = new A(QPixmap("a.png"));
    void go(){
        a->start();
    }
private:
    A *a;
}
```

P.S. I delete moveTimer in changePosition as long as the object stops moving and recall moveObject so that it can move towards the next target.

Comment: Where in your code does the seg fault occur? Have you run this under a debugger?

Comment: @G.M. yes. it occurs when moveObjects wants to be invoked for the second time

Comment: I presume you mean `moveObject` rather than `moveObjects`?  In which case -- regardless of the seg fault -- you appear to have a potential memory leak as you reallocate a new `QTimer` for `moveTimer` each time `moveObject` is called.